# Maclaurin series

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

Can someone tells me, why is that not working? 
I'm starting to learn Mathematica. I have to solved this eq and draw the graph. It is developing a series of Taylor in about x0 = 0.

```
eq = 60 - 53 x - 13 x^2 + 5 x^3 + x^4
seq = Solve[eq == 0, x]
p1 = D[eq, x]
s1 = Solve[p1 == 0, x]
f1 = seq + s1/1! x^1
z = Solve[f1, x]
Plot[z, {x, 0, 2}]
```

This is my equation to solve
[image: This is my equation to solve]

Comment: Don't be shy.Show your `p1` to us.

Comment: Oh, im so sorry, edited :)

Comment: Okay guys, i have to do 10-order polynomial, but i have to by using **Table[]**. Can you give me short tip how to do this? Although the 1-row, and the rest I will do same.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to belong on a site dedicated to homework assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eq = 60 - 53 x - 13 x^2 + 5 x^3 + x^4;
```

The roots are

```
seq = Solve[eq == 0, x]

{{x -> -5}, {x -> -4}, {x -> 1}, {x -> 3}}
```

The first order series expansion about zero is

```
f1 = Series[eq, {x, 0, 1}] // Normal

60 - 53 x

z = Solve[f1 == 0, x][[1]]

{x -> 60/53}
```

Plotting the polynomial and approximation and highlighting the roots

```
Plot[{eq, f1}, {x, -5.5, 3.5},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5],
   Point[{x, eq} /. seq],
   Point[{x, f1} /. z]},
 PlotRange -> {-50, 100},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Looking closer at the region of interest

```
Plot[{eq, f1}, {x, -0.5, 2},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5],
   Point[{x, eq} /. seq],
   Point[{x, f1} /. z]},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]