# Maclaurin Series - Table

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I'm starting to learn Mathematica. I have to solved this eq and draw the graph. It is developing a series of Taylor in about `x0 == 0`.
This is my equation to solve

[image: This is my equation to solve]

```
eq = 60 - 53 x - 13 x^2 + 5 x^3 + x^4
seq = Solve[eq == 0, x]
f1 = Series[eq, {x, 0, 1}] // Normal
```

And i have done plot, based on [this answer to my previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110979/29734). My next step is do 10-order polynomial, but i have to do it by using `Table[]`. Can you give me short tip how to do this? Although the 1-row, and the rest I will do same.

Comment: I have edited to your post to include a link to the previous answer you got. Please consider acknowledging help in this way in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
eq = 60 - 53 x - 13 x^2 + 5 x^3 + x^4;

g[k_][x_] := Series[eq, {x, 0, k}] // Normal
```

Since you are doing the series expansion about zero, all expansions with order greater than or equal to `4` will return the original polynomial (`eq`).

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[
  Table[
   Tooltip[g[k][x], "k = " <> ToString[k]],
   {k, 0, 4}]],
 {x, -5, 5},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]